# Is my device rooted if I can delete system app, but doesn't have SU installed?

Tags: root-access, tablet

I recently bought a new Allwinner A13 tablet. I wanted to side load Google Search app, but because there is already Google Search system app, it conflicted and failed to install.

Knowing this would be impossible without root, I still downloaded Root Explorer and navigated to `/system/app` and deleted the Google search app. To my surprise, it's deleted successfully. I rebooted the tab 4 times and the file is not in `/system/app`. So, I was able to side load my Google app.

Does this mean my tab is already rooted even though it's brand new and doesn't have SU installed?

Comment: check ur device root status by https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joeykrim.rootcheck&hl=en https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.freeandroidtools.root_checker&hl=en

Comment: Aside from checking with a root checking app from the Play Store, if the app your trying to install is a lower version or for a different device you will get a failed install as well. Possible reason, if not rooted, app was able to be uninstalled would be that it wasn't a system app,just installed into userspace.

Comment: By "SU installed", did you mean the su binary (that gives root access), or SU (probably Superuser) app, which can be installed from Play Store?

Comment: @HasH_BrowN I agree but OP didn't say he uninstalled it using some external app or using default un-installation (GUI) method in Android. He simply deleted the `.apk` (associated data possibly is still there). That said, about the last part of your comment. If his device is not rooted then he can do the un-installation but not deletion by going into restricted file-space (`/data` or `/system`) as a normal user.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Hussain's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/109287/44325) (whether the existence of SU app tells the device is rooted or not), the fact that you can access `/system` folder gives a strong indicator that your device is already rooted.

Note that it seems [A13 tablets usually come pre-rooted](http://www.slatedroid.com/topic/35314-a13-generic-tablet/#entry404394); they are already rooted when out from factory.

> From the little bit I'm seeing of these A13 tablets, [...] , and I can get root, which most people seem to agree that **they usually come pre-rooted**, [...]

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

Comment: +1 OP did say that the device *doesn't have SU installed*. But should SU  be construed as a binary or an app? It makes sense for an app at first glance but SU itself is no app in Play Store. Its either SuperSu or Superuser (others mostly are obsolete). Also SU is usually referred to either su binary or to say SuperUser (as root), not to mention [su]. Anyway, do you have a reason why you considered OP's word as an app rather than a binary?

Comment: @Firelord honestly, just a hunch, since some people mistaken SU with Superuser or SuperSU due to the name similarity (SU is Super User, and there's Superuser app, which only lacks a space, and SuperSU which contains SU). I'll ask OP for confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

SU is just another app for managing root access permissions on your device, if it's not present on your device, doesn't mean that your device is rooted or not.

For checking your device's root status, there are plenty of apps on Google Play Store which can help you. [keshav has mentioned some of them](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/109230/is-my-device-rooted-if-i-can-delete-system-app-but-doesnt-have-su-installed/109293#comment134712_109230).

I generally use Titanium Backup for system app removal tasks, etc. Also, when you run Titanium Backup on your device, it shows you whether your device has root access or not.